# How can I debug CRM 2011 activity workflow with plugin registration tool?

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, workflow-activity

I've been doing this with plugins, and it's really useful stuff because you don't need be attached to the IIS process.

This tutorial explain how to do that locally: http://athulmt.blogspot.it/2012/09/debugging-plugin-in-crm-2011.html

Now I'm trying to debug CRM 2011 activity workflows with the plugin registration tool, but didn't find any way to do that because I don't know workflows.

Comment: I think that site is a rip-off. I'd swear that I've seen those images before somewhere... It's like he just copied all the contents from somewhere... But maybe I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see this link:
[Debugging Workflow Custom Activities with Plugin Registration Tool](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/microsoftdynamicscrmandstuff/archive/2013/03/08/debugging-workflow-custom-activities-with-plugin-registration-tool)

Here is a link to a step by step guide to use it for plug-ins just as a reference:
[Step by Step: Working with CRM2011 plugin profiler](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2778280)